# Rails doesn't apply migration on test SQLite DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are DB settings

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

Here is the model migration

```
class CreateStocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :stocks, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :ticker
      t.string :name
      t.string :sector
      t.decimal :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Executing tests like `rails test`,
got this error

```
Error:
StockTest#test_stock_creation:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'stocks'
    test/models/stock_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StockTest>'
```

PS. On the develop DB the migration works fine

Comment: did you see the line of code `require "rails/test_help"` in your `test_helper.rb` ?

Comment: What happens when you try to run the migrations for the test environment with `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`?

Comment: In order to run your tests, your test database will need to have the current structure. This can be done by executing `bin/rails db:test:prepare`

Comment: @LamPhan, I have following code at the beginning of ```test_helper.rb```        ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!,
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test',
require_relative "../config/environment",
require "rails/test_help"

Comment: @spickermann nothing happens

Comment: @NitinSrivastava `bin/rails db:test:prepare` not affects on test db